# Viviani on Sphere parametrization

Tags: geometry, surfaces

How should parametrization of the 2 parameter surface  of a sphere (latitude u, longitude

v) be changed to result in 1 parameter curve of Viviani?

Comment: For reference: [Viviani's Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani's_curve)

Comment: @Blue Thanks. The parametrization of circle should get exactly transformed to that of viviani.(BTW, the cylinder depicted there looks more like a cone).

Answer (score 1):

The parametrization of the 2-sphere is given by
$$\vec{x}(u,v) = (\cos(v)\sin(u),\sin(v)\sin(u),\cos(u)).$$

The equation for a cylinder of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ and center at $\left(\frac{1}{2},0,0\right)$ is 
$$ \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+y^2=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Thus the intersection of the sphere and the cylinder is determined by
$$ \left(\cos(v)\sin(u)-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+(\sin(v)\sin(u))^2 = \frac{1}{4}$$
and we derive
$$ \sin(u) = \cos(v).$$

We therefore have a parametrization $(u(t),v(t)) = \left(t,\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)$ for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$.
We have 
$$\vec{x}(u(t),v(t)) = (\sin(t)^2,\sin(t)\cos(t),\cos(t)).$$

Answer (score 0):

I was asking for changes needed in:

$$\vec{x}(u,v) = (\cos(v)\sin(u),\sin(v)\sin(u),\cos(u)).$$

to directly get after derivation:

$$\vec{x}(u(t),v(t)) = (\sin(t)^2,sin(t)cos(t),cos(t)).$$

OK, the asked change/substitution simply is:

$$ u = v , ( = t, here) $$

$(\pi/2 - u = latitude ,  v= longitude)$

This is so because the Viviani curve has this standard parameter link property of

spherical coordinates:

$$ latitude = longitude. $$

This is a little known property, imho.